# How to set subtitle with line no wrap

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

How to set subtitle with line no wrap, I can't find props to set subtitle line no wrap.

```
<ListItem
  key={key}
  title={value.title}
  subtitle={
    <Text style={{fontSize: 12}}>{value.subtitle}</Text>
  }
  leftAvatar={{source: {uri: value.AvatarUrl}}}
  bottomDivider
  rightTitle="11:00am"
  badge={{value: '1'}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListItem
  key={key}
  title={value.title}
  subtitle={
    <Text style={{fontSize: 12}} numberOfLines={1}>{value.subtitle}</Text>
  }
  leftAvatar={{source: {uri: value.AvatarUrl}}}
  bottomDivider
  rightTitle={<Text style={{fontSize: 12}}>11:30</Text>}
/>
```